# How to use CeateEvent with a UIApp application created with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, event-handling, mouseevent

Using Google Apps ScriptI created a panel with a submitbutton and an anchor .
If the user clicks on the button I want to activate the anchor and perform its actions as if it has been clicked itself.
So I thought generating a mouseclick on the anchor by CreateEvent would be sufficient.
But I can't find a way to generate that clickevent.

How can I do that(or achieve my goal differently) ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to just assign the same client / server handlers that the anchor has to the submit button. Try a regular button instead of submit if a form isn't involved. Can't create a mouse click event through code either.